# object has no attribute error in python

Tags: python, oop, linked-list, attributeerror

I am new to python programming and I have encountered an error for the below mentioned program. It is a simple program to add a node to the end of the linked list. The error says object LinkedList has no attribute head. Please Help me with the problem.

```
class Node:
    def _init_(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None

class LinkedList:
    def _init_(self):
        self.head=None

    def createNode(self, data):
        newNode = Node(data)
        return newNode

    def insertNodeHelper(self, head, data):
        if(head==None):
            return self.createNode(data)
        head.next = self.insertNodeHelper(head.next,data)
        return head

    def insertNode(self, data):
        self.head = self.insertNodeHelper(self.head,data)

    def printList(self, head):
        if(head==None):
            return;
        print(head.data)
        self.printList(head.next)

    def printLinkedList(self):
        self.printList(self.head)

l = LinkedList()
l.insertNode(12)
l.insertNode(13)
l.insertNode(15)
l.printList()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    <module1>   35      
    insertNode  <module1>   21      
AttributeError: 'LinkedList' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `def _init_(self):` to `def __init__(self):`(two underscore). Because this method is a constructor method, it must be writen in this form.